# How to add multiple Style Classes to a QtWidget

Tags: c++, css, qt

I add a Style class to a Qt widget as follows:

```
minimizeApp = new QPushButton();
minimizeApp -> setProperty("class", "undecorated-widgets");
```

The problem I'm having is that I can only add one style class to an element. If I try adding a second one the previous one gets lost.

How can I add multiple style classes to an element?

In Java this is possible through:

```
label.getStyleClass().addAll("style-class-1", "style-class-2", "......");
```

Is this possible in Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine the setProperty function sets the class attribute directly, so separating them with spaces like you would in html should work.

```
minimizeApp = new QPushButton();
minimizeApp -> setProperty("class", "undecorated-widgets second-class third-class");
```